# Why ObjectID is not defined in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, objectid

I try to query my MongoDB by finding particular "_id" but new ObjectID does not do the trick. And I try to create a variable hold a random ObjectID by "var obj = new ObjectID()" which does not work as well. Then I check my MongoDB version and it is up to date (db version v4.0.2). Server connection works fine. Any thoughts? Thanks.

My collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5bc9fe6683dfb93706fe8a24",
    "name": "Luis",
    "occupation": "Doctor"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bc9fe6683dfb93706fe8a25",
    "name": "Peter",
    "occupation": "Student"
  }
]
```

Mangodb code:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');



MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/NewApp',(err, client) => {

    if(err){
        return console.log("Unable to connect to MongoDB server");
    }


    console.log("Connect to MongoDB server");
    const db = client.db('NewApp');


    db.collection('Users').find({"_id": new ObjectID("5bc9fe6683dfb93706fe8a24")}).toArray().then((data) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

    },(error) => {

        if(error){console.log("Unable to fetch the data", error)}
    });


    client.close();
});
```

Error:

```
Connect to MongoDB server
/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:466
      throw err;
      ^

ReferenceError: ObjectID is not defined
at MongoClient.connect ...
```

Comment: do `npm i bson` and `require` `ObjectID` from it then you can call its constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace first line of your code with

```
const { MongoClient, ObjectID } = require('mongodb');
```

You need to import `ObjectID` class in order to use it.
You can see the list of all exports here:
https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/index.js

Comment: This worked for me: `import { MongoClient, ObjectId } from 'mongodb';`